# Подскажите где можно найти хорошие упражнения новичку? Python

Tags: python

Подскажите где можно новичку найти легкие упражнения что бы после можно было проверить самого себя ?

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/

Answer (score 0):

проверь сайт codewars(https://www.codewars.com) или Проект Эйлера(https://euler.jakumo.org/problems.html). Уверен, поможет улучшить навыки 100%.

Comment: простите, но проект эйлера для математиков.и уж точно не для начинающих програмистов.

Comment: Для кого предназначены задачи?
Целевая аудитория проекта включает в себя студентов, которым мало университетского курса, не-математиков, которым, тем не менее, интересна математика, а также профессионалов, которым хотят быть в хорошей математической форме.